# Program starts misbehaving after a certain threshold

Tags: java

I have a homework task as follows:

> The bin packing problem is to pack the objects of
>   various weights into containers. Assume each
>   container can hold a maximum of 10 pounds. The
>   program uses an algorithm that places an object into
>   the first bin in which it would fit. Your program should
>   prompt the user to enter the total number of objects
>   and the weight of each object. The program displays
>   the total number of containers needed to pack the
>   objects and the content of each container. Here is a
>   simple run of the program:

- Enter the number of objects: 6
- Enter the weight of the objects: 7 5 2 3 5 8
- Container 1 contains objects with weight: 7 2
- Container 2 contains objects with weight: 5 3
- Container 3 contains objects with weight: 5
- Container 4 contains objects with weight: 8

Now I have decided to try making it smarter and optimize the object allocation. It seemed to be working fine, but when I started testing using more numbers than the sample run I noticed that the highest I can go is 27 objects. Anything higher and I start getting a few containers at the end of the execution that could be merged into a single one. Any ideas and suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance!

```
package classwork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinPacking {

private static final int binLimit = 10;

public static boolean lessThanLimit(int a, int b) {
    if (a + b < binLimit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean perfectFit(int a, int b) {
    if (a + b == binLimit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean weightsLeft(boolean[] a) { // check if there is one more item that has not been binned yet.
    for (boolean b : a) {
        if (b) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static ArrayList<int[]> distributeObjects(int[] weights) {
    int counter = 0;
    boolean[] objectAssigned = new boolean[weights.length]; // array to track which objects have been assigned already
    ArrayList<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>(); // list of int[] to be returned
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> currentBin = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // list to store the values of the weights in currrent bin
        int currentBinWeight = 6;
        if (!objectAssigned[i]) {
            currentBin.add(weights[i]);
            currentBinWeight = weights[i];
            objectAssigned[i] = true;
        } else
            counter = 1;

        stupidLoopThatWontBreak: 
        while (currentBinWeight < binLimit && counter < 1) {
            counter = 1;
            if (!weightsLeft(objectAssigned)) { // break loop if no more weights left
                result.add(currentBin.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());
                break stupidLoopThatWontBreak;
            }
            for (int j = i + 1; j < weights.length; j++) {
                if (perfectFit(currentBinWeight, weights[j]) && !objectAssigned[j]) {
                    currentBin.add(weights[j]);
                    currentBinWeight += weights[j];
                    objectAssigned[j] = true;
                    break stupidLoopThatWontBreak;
                }
                if (lessThanLimit(currentBinWeight, weights[j]) && !objectAssigned[j]) {
                    currentBinWeight += weights[j];
                    currentBin.add(weights[j]);
                    objectAssigned[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // convert arraylist to int[] and add it to result. Java 8+ feature
        if (!currentBin.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(currentBin.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.err.println("Container weight limit is " + binLimit);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Test numbers 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 8
    // System.out.print("Enter the weights of the objects you want to put into the bins: ");
    // String input = in.nextLine();
    // in.close();
//========================Random numbers for testing======================
    String input = "";
    Random ran = new Random();
    System.out.print("Enter number of weights to be randomly generated: ");
    int num = in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        input += (ran.nextInt(binLimit) + 1) + " "; //+1 to not have zeroes
    }
//========================End of random numbers===========================
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] str = input.trim().split(" "); // trim surrounding spaces, use space char as separator
    for (String a : str) {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(a));
    }

    // sort the list in a descending order
    Collections.sort(list);
    Collections.reverse(list); // this could be avoided if I started checking from the last index in distributeObjects()
    System.out.println("The generated and sorted descendingly weights are:");
    System.out.println("\n" + list.toString() + "\n");

    int[] weights = new int[list.size()];
    for (int a = 0; a < weights.length; a++) {
        weights[a] = list.get(a);
    }

    ArrayList<int[]> bins = distributeObjects(weights);

    for (int i = 0; i < bins.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Container " + (i + 1) + " contains objects with weight: " + Arrays.toString(bins.get(i)));
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you split your code in to multiple methods, each doing part of the job. It's hard to get a full understanding of the code with so much happening in each method. Also, a List of int[] seems like a code smell, you should perhaps create classes for the central concepts of your program (Container for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I am posing this as an answer -

Run above code with "10 9 8 8 8 7 7 7 6 6 6 5 5 5 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1" as input array and you will see the problem being caused by 'counter' variable. If you replace 'counter=1;' from else with 'continue;' it should work for this input. You still need to test this for other inputs. Also, the above code needs refactoring - for example - use either list or weights. Both are nor required.

Answer (score 0):

I tried not to distort your code too much, but this should give you your desired output. The problem was with your second loop, it caused some trouble with the counter variable since counter was never set back to 0 at the end of your loop if the bin should not already be added (when you did not find the first weight that has to be added to the bin).

The easiest way to fix your program is simply to move `counter = 0;` inside the if statement where you check if there is already a weight inside of the bin or not outside of the if block.

I removed the "stupidLoopThatWouldNotBreak" below and replaced it with another for loop, that looks through all remaining weights if there is one that can fit.

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> distributeObjects(int[] weights) {

    boolean[] objectAssigned = new boolean[weights.length]; // array to track which objects have been assigned already
    ArrayList<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>(); // list of int[] to be returned

    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {

        ArrayList<Integer> currentBin = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // list to store the values of the weights in currrent bin
        int currentBinWeight = 0;

        //This loop searches for the first unused Weight, so you do not need `count` anymore
        for (int j = i; j < weights.length; j++) {
            if (!objectAssigned[j]) {
                currentBin.add(weights[j]);
                currentBinWeight = weights[j];
                objectAssigned[j] = true;
                break;
            }

            i = j; //You can skip all iterations with used weights
        }

        for (int j = i; j < weights.length && currentBinWeight < binLimit; j++) {

            if (perfectFit(currentBinWeight, weights[j]) && !objectAssigned[j]) {
                currentBin.add(weights[j]);
                currentBinWeight += weights[j];
                objectAssigned[j] = true;
                break; //this break gives some performance bonus
            }
            if (lessThanLimit(currentBinWeight, weights[j]) && !objectAssigned[j]) {
                currentBinWeight += weights[j];
                currentBin.add(weights[j]);
                objectAssigned[j] = true;
            }

        }


        // convert arraylist to int[] and add it to result. Java 8+ feature
        if (!currentBin.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(currentBin.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can further enhance your code if you split this loop up. You can add more functions like the two helperfunctions `perfectFit` and `lessThanlimit`. You can for example add another function that will search for the first empty element, maybe even add it to the bin. Also the 2 functions you already have could be merged into one function called `addWeight` or `attemptAdd`. Furthermore you could create seperate classes for the bin and for the weights.